# C++11 - "expected unqualified-id before 'nullptr' "

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I made some edits to my code, then did about 15 "Undo" operations to get back to where I last compiled successfully, only instead of compiling it came up with this never-before-seen error:

```
expected unqualified-id before 'nullptr'
```

Double-clicking the error brings me to the below section of `qcompilerdetection.h`, a file I never knew existed. How did my edits to my code possibly mess this file up? Or is this a misdirection of the real problem? I know I've had errors show up because of a missing bracket somewhere completely different in the code... So I checked every line of code I edited between last successful compile and this one. Unfortunately I'm an idiot and closed the program before "redo"ing everything to see if that fixed it. So now I have no idea what to change to fix and I'm too much of a noob to do anything without further corrupting my code.

```
/*
 * C++11 keywords and expressions
 */
#ifdef Q_COMPILER_NULLPTR
# define Q_NULLPTR         nullptr
#else
# define Q_NULLPTR         NULL
#endif

#ifdef Q_COMPILER_DEFAULT_MEMBERS
#  define Q_DECL_EQ_DEFAULT = default
#else
#  define Q_DECL_EQ_DEFAULT
#endif

#ifdef Q_COMPILER_DELETE_MEMBERS
# define Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE = delete
#else
# define Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE
#endif
```

Specifically this point:

```
# define Q_NULLPTR         nullptr
                           ^
```

If it helps to know, I was working on setting up a QThread in Qt5 on a Raspberry Pi 3. Never seen issues like this before, only errors in code I actually wrote. Is this where I debugger comes in handy? I've no idea how to use one in Qt Creator.

and if it helps to see... This is the code I was working on.

in `press.cpp`

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "press.h"

#define PUMP 21
#define SOLENOID_DWN 24
#define SOLENOID_UP 25
#define LIGHT_LEFT 26
#define LIGHT_RIGHT 27
#define LASER 28
#define ENCODER_A 0
#define ENCODER_B 2
#define PEDAL_RIGHT 12
#define PEDAL_LEFT 13
#define HOME 14

Press::Press()
{

}

void Press::programRun() {
    qDebug() << "Hunting Position...";
    qDebug() << positionTarget;
    digitalWrite(PUMP,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(SOLENOID_DWN,HIGH);
    upFlag = 0;
    while (pos > positionTarget){
        if (stopFlag == 1){
            emit stop();
            qDebug() << "emit stopped";
            return;
        }
        if (pausedFlag == 1){
            if (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){
                //Functions::programUnpause();
                emit resume();
                qDebug() << "emit resumed";
                delay(100);
                while (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){}
                delay(100);
            }
        }
        if (digitalRead(PEDAL_RIGHT) == LOW){
            emit stop();
            //Functions::programStop();
            delay(100);
            while (digitalRead(PEDAL_RIGHT) == LOW){}
            delay(100);
        }
        if (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){
            //Functions::programPause();
            emit pause();
            delay(100);
            while (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){}
            delay(100);
        }
        delayMicroseconds(30);
    }
    //Functions::solenoidOff();
    //Functions::solenoidUp();
    upFlag = 1;
    //Functions::programPause();
    emit pause();
    while (digitalRead(HOME) == HIGH){
        if (stopFlag == 1){
            emit stop();
            qDebug() << "emit stopped";
            return;
        }
        if (pausedFlag == 1){
            if (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){
                //Functions::programUnpause();
                emit resume();
                qDebug() << "emit resumed";
                delay(100);
                while (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){}
                delay(100);
            }
        }
        if (digitalRead(PEDAL_RIGHT) == LOW){
            emit stop();
            //Functions::programStop();
            delay(100);
            while (digitalRead(PEDAL_RIGHT) == LOW){}
            delay(100);
        }
        if (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){
            //Functions::programPause();
            emit pause();
            qDebug() << "emit paused";
            delay(100);
            while (digitalRead(PEDAL_LEFT) == LOW){}
            delay(100);
        }
        delayMicroseconds(30);
    }
    qDebug() << "FINISHED";
    emit stop();
    Functions::solenoidOff();
}
```

and in `main.cpp`

```
#include <QCursor>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QObject>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "datahandler.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "press.h"

#define PUMP 21
#define SOLENOID_DWN 24
#define SOLENOID_UP 25
#define LIGHT_LEFT 26
#define LIGHT_RIGHT 27
#define LASER 28
#define ENCODER_A 0
#define ENCODER_B 2
#define PEDAL_RIGHT 12
#define PEDAL_LEFT 13
#define HOME 14

QScopedPointer<Functions> myFunctions(new Functions);
QScopedPointer<DataHandler> myData(new DataHandler);

QThread* thread = new QThread;
Press* pressProgram = new Press();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::BlankCursor ) );    //Hide the cursor

    pressProgram->moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), pressProgram, SLOT (programRun()));
    QObject::connect(pressProgram, SIGNAL (stop()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
    QObject::connect(pressProgram, SIGNAL (stop()), thread, SLOT (deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(pressProgram, SIGNAL (stop()), pressProgram, SLOT (deleteLater()));
    //thread->start();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pressProgram",pressProgram);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myFunctions",myFunctions.data());
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myData",myData.data());
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("noteProfileArray",noteProfileArray);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Errors in header files normally occur while compiling some implementation (`.cpp`) file. Which implementation file was being compiled when this error occurred?

Comment: Once you have narrowed down which cpp file is reporting the error, start carving stuff out. You shouldn't need any of your code to reproduce the error, just the include statements. Comment out everything after the last include. Build. If the error goes away, shoot. I'm wrong. One by one add each function back in until it doesn't build. Now you know which function is the problem start  commenting out bits of the function to narrow the problem down further. If I'm right, start commenting out headers one by one. Narrow the search area down.

Comment: Not sure how to check which `.cpp` file is underway when error hits. I'll start googling "Qt Creator Debugging"

Comment: @daGriggs You could start by trying to manufacture [mcve]. One way of doing it, would be: start taking stuff out, of your project, until it stops failing.

Comment: Thank you, I tried some removal, and found it made things more complicated as chain-events of broken #includes or class calls occurred. Luckily I spotted the culprit line of code and fixed the issue. Good general debugging advice though for anyone else who reads this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this falls into the 99% of all cases: syntax error.

Found an errant line of code in something I didn't think I had edited, and that wasn't singled out by the IDE, but needed fixing. As I suspected, the header file error was a misdirection, and I really appreciated the comment:

"Errors in header files normally occur while compiling some `.cpp` file."

Good to know that my code did not directly break compiler-level files, but rather caused any number of weird background things to go wrong, manifesting in what looked like a mean deeply-rooted issue.

Sidenote: I believe I made this mistake because I edited multiple .cpp files and must have forgotten to "Undo" one of them. I wish there was a way to globally undo actions in a Qt Creator project.

Comment: Consider using source control.